# Flutter dropdownlist is populated too slow

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a dropdownlist and list items are fetched from webapi.
From time to time fetching json takes a while and dropdownlist can't be binded successfully. An exception is thrown:

```
I/flutter (21159): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21159): The following assertion was thrown building ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(dirty):
I/flutter (21159): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 481 pos 15: 'value == null ||
I/flutter (21159): items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.
```

My code:

```
  Widget _buildDropDownList(MainModel model) {

      isEmpty: itemId == 0,
      child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
          value: itemId != 0 ? itemId .toString() : null,
          isDense: true,
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              itemId = model.allItems
                  .where((x) => x.itemId == int.parse(newValue))
                  .first
                  .itemId;
            });
          },
          items: model.allItems.map((Item item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item.itemId.toString(),
              child: new Text(item.itemName),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I think that this is caused by time-related issues, because when i set

```
value = null
```

then dropdownlist is populated correctly, but of course none element is selected.

Comment: maybe the `itemId` is like a huge string and comparing it takes long time?

Comment: no it is integer less then 10000 number